# How to parse interactively syslog on remote host

Tags: python, syslog, pexpect

I need to implement in Python the following:

1. Connect to remote host (CentOS 6.5 based).
2. Interactively parse the syslog (/var/log/messages) and expect for some specific message.
3. On message arriving parse it and verify some things.

I have no problem with (1) and (3). On other hand have no idea how to do the (2).
I assume it can be done by using pexpect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Post some example use cases. *"Interactively parse the syslog and expect for some specific message."* doesn't mean much to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some specific script for parsing /var/log/messages on server or use some tool or command for it and send result to shell stdout. For example(sorry for trivial):

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@host')
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('secure_word')
child.expect(']$')
child.sendline('less /var/log/messages')
child.expect('/^some_data_need_to_get$/')
```

In this case **less** command(instead of **less** can be some script) return output into shell stdout and you can find with regexp some data you need. In 4 line described some prompt we expect.